# Query with sum and count in 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I use 2 tables for my php scripts.

```
define("EXTRA_POINTS_VALUE",15);

table "points":
id_user | point
   1    |  500
   2    |  650
   3    |  400

table "points_extra":
id_point_extra | id_user
   1           |   1
   2           |   1
   3           |   1
   4           |   2
```

i have need of SUM field "points.point" with COUNT(id_extra_point) * EXTRA_POINTS_VALUE in one query. It's possible?

The result must be as this:

```
id_user | total_point
   1    |     545     (500 + (3 count * 15))
   2    |     665     (650 + (1 count * 15))
   3    |     400     (400 + (0 count * 15))
```

Comment: And your approach is..?

Comment: What query have you tried so far?

Comment: also you results have a typo... for id_user=2 it should be `665 = (650 + (1 Count * 15))

Comment: is the `id_user` *unique* in table `points`?

Comment: yes, points.id_user is unique primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.id_user,
        a.point + (COUNT(b.id_point_extra) * ?) totalPoints
FROM    points a
        LEFT JOIN points_extra b
            ON a.id_user = b.id_user
GROUP   BY a.id_user
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b76ae/3)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have changed only this: COUNT(b.id_user)